# Delphi Stopwatch time format

Tags: delphi, time, format, delphi-xe5, stopwatch

```
procedure TForm1.TimerSWTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
 Hour, Min, Sec, MSec: word;
begin
 ElapsedTime := Time - StartTime + Totaltime ;
 DecodeTime(elapsedtime, Hour, Min, Sec, MSec);
 LabelSW.Text := IntToStr(Hour)  + ':'+ IntToStr(Min) + ':'+ IntToStr(Sec) + ':' + IntToStr(Msec);
end;
```

This is the code for stopwatch that I am  trying to implement into my application, the main problem is that the time format shown on the label is `0:0:0:0`, and I would like it to be `00:00:00:000` for hours, minutes, seconds and miliseconds. I have tried numerous things and codes that i found online but none of it helped me.

When i start the stopwatch, the time goes like this `0:0:0:1`, than `0:0:0:10`, `0:0:0:100`, and after a full second miliseconds go to 1 decimal (1 instead 001). Same thing for hours, minutes and seconds, they are shown on 1 decimal until they reach 10 (9 instead 09)..

I have tried:

- Addleadingzeroes function

  Usage:

  ```
  AddLeadingZeroes(2005, 10) ;
  ```

  Will result in a '0000002005' string value.
- Time only - numeric values with leading zeroes

  ```
  ShowMessage('hh:nn:ss.zzz = '+FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss.zzz', myDate));
  ```

If any of you good chaps can help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Cheers.

Comment: And what about [`System.Diagnostics.TStopWatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch)?

Comment: labelSW.Text := Format('%2.2u:%2.2u:%2.2u:%3.3u',[Hour,Min,Sec,MSec]); See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format

Comment: @SirRufo I am sorry, I am not very adapt at this, found this example online to implement, I dont know how to use Tstopwatch atm, havent tried tbh.

Comment: @LURD Thank you very much sir, it works, everything except the Milliseconds, they always jump from 00:101 to 00:201 to 00:301, its always a round number, but i will look into it. THanks guys a lot!

Comment: As it should be if your timer interval is 100 msec

Comment: @TomBrunberg exactly! How can i thank you veterans, can i give u reputation point? Dont see an option.

Comment: I made an answer so you can vote/accept :-)

Comment: @LURD least I could do! Cheers

Comment: I'm really curious why `FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss.zzz', myDate);` didn't work for? It should have done the trick. So what happened when you tried that?

Comment: You have reinvented the wheel. As @Sir Rufo already mentioned, the `System.Diagnostics.TStopWatch` does already what you do. And can format the elapsed time just as you want by the implicit class operator for string, so a line like `S := StopWatch.Elapsed;` where `S` is a string variable and `StopWatch` is a `TStopWatch` variable will give you just what you want.

Comment: @TLama, I agree that `TStopWatch` is a good (preferred) utility for measuring time. But formatting the output with the implicit TTimeSpan class operator does not give the wanted result. If milliseconds are zero, that part is omitted from the string and otherwise gives 7 digits, example `00:00:00.0000137`.

Comment: @LURD, you are right, I should have check that deeper.

Comment: @TLama, I added an example using `TStopWatch` and an alternate way of formatting the output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format

```
labelSW.Text := Format('%2.2u:%2.2u:%2.2u:%3.3u',[Hour,Min,Sec,MSec]);
```

The precision specifier makes left padding with zeroes.

---

Using the RTL `TStopwatch` advanced record in System.Diagnostics, it gets a little easier:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Diagnostics;

var
  sw: TStopwatch;
...
sw := TStopwatch.StartNew;  // Start measuring time
...
procedure TForm1.TimerSWTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LabelSW.Text := 
    FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss:zzz',sw.ElapsedMilliseconds/MSecsPerDay); 
end;
```